# How to handle custom errors in webonyx/graphql-php?

Tags: php, graphql-php

I'm creating some graphql queries using webonyx/graphql-php and the documentation is very incomplete explaining how to handle custom errors during a resolving of a query. For example, if the user app send a query looking for some record, I would like to return a custom error "Customer not found", not only this ugly structure

```
[
    'debugMessage' => 'Actual exception message',
    'message' => 'Internal server error',
    'category' => 'internal',
    'locations' => [
        ['line' => 10, 'column' => 2]
    ],
    'path' => [
        'listField',
        0,
        'fieldWithException'
    ],
    'trace' => [
        /* Formatted original exception trace */
    ]
];
```

I read a lot of times the docs (https://webonyx.github.io/graphql-php/error-handling/)  but cant understand how to do it. Could you help me please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For generating a custom error message you can move on with one of the method below,

Let your schema declaration be like :-

```
$schema = new Schema(['query' => --your queries-- , 'mutation' => --your mutations-- , ......]);

$result = GraphQL::executeQuery($schema, $requestQuery);
```

To convert the graphql object into array structure add the steps below:

```
$result->toArray();

if (!empty($result['errors'])) {
   $result = ['errors' => [['message' => $result['errors'][0]['message']]]];
}
```

For returning custom error message from Graphql object add the codes below and skip the object to array conversion steps,

```
if (!empty($result->errors)) {
   $result = ['errors' => [['message' => $result->errors[0]->getMessage()]]];
    
    // The getMessage() method will always be in the 0th index of the errors object
}
```

Add the lines below for returning the response:-

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

You can generate your error message inside your function like:-

```
use GraphQL\Error\Error;

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM customer_table where id='1'")

if(empty($result)) 
  {
     throw new Error("Customer not found.");
  }
```

You can have the response structure like below:-

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "Customer not found."
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation states that in order to customize the response sent when an exception is thrown, one needs to throw a custom `Exception` class that implements the interface `ClientAware` and returns `true` in the `isClientSafe` method.

That is to say that you would need to declare an `Exception` class as follows:

```php
class CustomerNotFound extends \Exception implements ClientAware
{
  protected $message = 'Customer not found';

  public function isClientSafe()
  {
      return true;
  }

  public function getCategory()
  {
      return 'missing';
  }
}
```

and in your application logic, when no customer record is found, throw the above exception class, similar to:

```php
if ($rowCount < 1)
{
  throw new CustomerNotFound;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! But in this case ( I couldn't understand it) I'll need to call this CustomerNotFound Within the resolver or I'll need call in other situation? I can create an Exception for it, but... when can I call this implementation? Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, you would throw the exception in the resolver if the record isn't found.